Llava learns to produce structured output but the content is inaccurate
I want to use Llava to automatically label my image dataset. The labelling output should be a JSON with some information, e.g. {'animal_list': ['dog', 'cat'], 'image_quality': 'blurred', ...}. I manually labelled a few hundred images using the desired schema and built a dataset using the format described here. Specifically, the human message is always the same:

Describe the following image taken from [...], focusing on
[...]. Use the following schema: GT_SCHEMA

, where GT_SCHEMA is the desired JSON schema, and the gpt message is the JSON output. I trained Llava 1.6 using LoRA (training script at the end).
The model learned to provide the answer in the desired JSON format. However, the output is often inaccurate (for example, animal_list not including an animal in the image). I checked that the base model is able to identify all the elements that I need when I prompt it with a free description request, so the problem is the finetuning with this format. How can I improve the accuracy of the structured labeling?
#!/bin/bash

export DATA_PATH=/home/ubuntu/data/structured
export IMG_PATH=/home/ubuntu/data/structured
export OUTPUT_DIR=/home/ubuntu/models/llava-v1.6-vicuna-13b-lora

deepspeed llava/train/train_mem.py \
    --lora_enable True --lora_r 16 --lora_alpha 16 --mm_projector_lr 1e-5 \
    --deepspeed ./scripts/zero3_offload.json \
    --model_name_or_path liuhaotian/llava-v1.6-vicuna-13b \
    --version v1 \
    --data_path $DATA_PATH/dataset \
    --image_folder $IMG_PATH \
    --vision_tower openai/clip-vit-large-patch14-336 \
    --mm_projector_type mlp2x_gelu \
    --mm_vision_select_layer -2 \
    --mm_use_im_start_end False \
    --mm_use_im_patch_token False \
    --image_aspect_ratio pad \
    --group_by_modality_length True \
    --bf16 True \
    --output_dir $OUTPUT_DIR \
    --num_train_epochs 3 \
    --per_device_train_batch_size 4 \
    --per_device_eval_batch_size 4 \
    --gradient_accumulation_steps 1 \
    --evaluation_strategy "no" \
    --save_strategy "steps" \
    --save_steps 80 \
    --save_total_limit 3 \
    --learning_rate 2e-4 \
    --weight_decay 0. \
    --warmup_ratio 0.03 \
    --lr_scheduler_type "cosine" \
    --logging_steps 1 \
    --tf32 True \
    --model_max_length 2048 \
    --gradient_checkpointing True \
    --dataloader_num_workers 4 \
    --lazy_preprocess True \
    --report_to wandb



How can I improve the accuracy of the structured labeling?

Likely, simply with more finetuning data. Plot finetuning data size vs. accuracy to check  if the model is learning something and has potential to learn more.
